# How do I stop the loop from going past 12 months?

Tags: python

I need the loop to stop at 12 months and not count all the way up to how many months it takes to reach the goal. I just need it to print how many months it takes to reach the goal but not count all the way to it. I only need it to go up to 12 months. For example if I input an original deposit for 1000, 4.5 interest rate, 12 months, and 1200 goal amount then I want it to only show it counting to 12 months not 49. I still need it to print out how many months it takes to reach the goal at the end but I do not need it to show it counting all the way up to 49. I am sorry if this sounds confusing.

```
#Keep asking until the user puts in a positive numeric value using loops
fDeposit = 0
while fDeposit <= 0:
  try:
    fDeposit = float(input('What is the original deposit (positive value): '))
    if fDeposit <= 0:
     print("Input must be a positive numerical value: ")
  except ValueError:
    print("Input must be a numeric value")

fInterest = 0
while fInterest <= 0:
  try:
    fInterest = float(input('What is the Interest Rate (positive value): '))
    if fInterest <= 0:
      print("Input must be a positive numerical value: ")
  except ValueError:
    print("Input must be a numeric value")

iMonths = 0
while iMonths <= 0:
  try:
    iMonths = int(input('What is the number of months (positive value): '))
    if iMonths <= 0:
      print("Input must be a positive numerical value: ")
  except ValueError:
    print("Input must be a numeric value")

fGoal = None
while fGoal == None:
  try:
    fGoal = float(input('What is the goal amount (Can enter 0 but not negative): '))
    if fGoal < 0:
      print("Input must be a positive numerical value: ")
      fGoal = None
  except ValueError:
    print("Input must be a numeric value")

# Calculate Interest. First convert the variable to a decimal by dividing by 100 then divide 
that by 12
fMonthlyInterest= (fInterest/100/12)

#Output the number of months the user has supplied and get account balance
i = 1
fAccountBalance = fDeposit
while i <= fAccountBalance:
  if fAccountBalance >= fGoal:
    break
  fInterestForMonth = (fAccountBalance * fMonthlyInterest)
  #Add the interest for the month to the deposit to get the new Account Balance
  fAccountBalance += fInterestForMonth 
  print('Month: ',i, 'Account Balance is: $',format(fAccountBalance, ",.2f"))
  i += 1
# Calculate how many months it will take of compounding to reach the goal amount
GoalFormatted = "{:.2f}".format(fGoal)
CompoundedSavingsAccountBalance = fMonthlyInterest + fAccountBalance
while CompoundedSavingsAccountBalance < fGoal:
  iMonths += 1 
print('It will take: ',i-1, 'months to reach the goal of $', GoalFormatted)
```

Comment: This loop is probably wrong: `while i <= fAccountBalance`. You're comparing a month index (1-12) with an account balance. Once you correct that, you could enhance the condition with `and i <= 12`. Also, Python programmers do not use type prefixes on Python variable names (such as `fAccountBalance` for a float or `iMonths` for an int).

Comment: I dont like putting the i or f in front of the variables but thats how my python professor wants us to do it

Comment: Ill try your suggestion thank you

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem, add "if i < 12:" after line 52, and indent the next line where you printing the month & the account balance. The completed section is below.

```
i = 1
fAccountBalance = fDeposit
while i <= fAccountBalance:
  if fAccountBalance >= fGoal:
    break
  fInterestForMonth = (fAccountBalance * fMonthlyInterest)
  #Add the interest for the month to the deposit to get the new Account Balance
  fAccountBalance += fInterestForMonth 
  if i <= 12:
    print('Month: ',i, 'Account Balance is: $',format(fAccountBalance, ",.2f"))
  i += 1
```

Comment: So the issue is I need it to go past 12 so If I put 15 months in I need it to go to that. I am supposed to code another loop my professor says You need to code TWO loops and output two different outcomes:
-Monthly interest based on what the user entered using the Months. I'd use a for loop
-Goal loop to see how long it will take to grow the initial investment to 1200.

Comment: he says I am missing a loop

Comment: I tried putting 15 in with your code and it wouldnt print out any months unfortunetly